# C2011 'class' type redefinition

Tags: c++

I keep getting a "class type redefinition error". I have read several solutions online that suggest adding `#prgma once` or  `#ifndef GBMAP_H` & `#define GBMAP_H`, but none of them are solving the problem. So even if i strip the code bare-bones i still get the issue.
I have a GBMap.cpp

```
#include "GBMap.h"

class GBMap {

};
```

GBMap.h

```
#pragma once

#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class GBMap {

};
```

Why is class GBMap being redefined?

Comment: As far as I know you shouldn't declare class in `*.cpp` files.

Comment: *Why is class GBMap being redefined?* – because you have one definition `class GBMap{};` in `GBMap.cpp` and one definition one definition `class GBMap{};` in `GBMap.h`!? Definition of the class (`class GBMap{ /* declaration of members */ };`) goes in `GBMap.h` and the definition of the members of `GBMap` goes in `GBMap.cpp`.

Comment: If you are trying to implement class members of the `GBMap` class in the cpp file this is not how you do that.

Answer (score 3):

Your file `GBMap.cpp` contains two definitions for the class `GBMap`. One you have written directly, and the other definition you have included from the file GBMap.h. After the inclusion, the translation unit looks like this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class GBMap {

};

class GBMap {

};
```

As you can see, there are clearly two definitions for the class.

There may not be more than one definition of a class per translation unit, hence the error. Solution: Change the program so that there is only one definition of the class.

Answer (score 2):

It's being redefined because you define it twice:

```
// You can think of this as a cut and paste of GBMap.h so there's now
// a definition of GBMap here
#include "GBMap.h"

// And now you have a 2nd one.
class GBMap {

};
```

The typical pattern is something like:

In GMap.h:

```
// This makes sure that if GMap.h is #included twice (including
// transitively) that the compiler only reads it once so you don't
// get the multiple definition error.
#pragma once

#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

// Define the class in the .h file
class GBMap {
 public:
  // This is just an example method to show what goes in the .cpp
  // Note that this method is declared here (we know it exists) but
  // not defined (we don't know what code to run if it's called)
  void SayHi() const;

};
```

In GBMap.cpp:

```
// Include the definition - do **not** define it again after this
// you now have essentially copied the definition from GMap.h here
#include "GMap.h"


// Now add the **definition** (not declaration) for one of the class's methods
void GBMap::SayHi() const {
   std::cout << "Hi!" << std::endl;
}
```